# Which function will execute the quickest?

Tags: sql, database, function, methods

i want to know which function will execute the fastest for my project.
Which function will be the **best for DB** ..

Also is there another method to accomplish the same task?

```
void function1 ()
{
  operation ;
  loop ()
  {
   method insertInDB ( string ) ;
  }
}

void insertInDB ()
{
   open connection ;
   insert;
   close ;
}
```

> OR

```
void function2 ()
{
  operation ;
  loop ()
  {
   string [];
  }
   method insertInDB (array []);
}
void insertInDB ()
{
  open connection ;
  loop ()
  {
   insert;
  }
  close ;
}
```

Comment: Batch inserts will work faster.

Comment: Did you try to time the execution of both methods to see which one is faster based upon your setup?   From the DB standpoint, fewer connections would be better.

Answer (score 1):

2nd. Because you will only open your BD connection one time to insert your data and close. :)